# Why when I open multi-browsers with DIFFERENT profiles I get a million errors?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to try to open a site with different profiles almost instantly. But when I run my code, it works correctly every once in a while, and when I use .get (URL), it closes all windows, then opens the site only on the first browser.

```
import threading

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


ANTI_LAG_DELAY = 0.5 # nwm
ALL_PROFILES = 10
URL = "http://www.google.com"

prefix_for_profiles = 'Testing'
chrome_exe_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
chrome_profile_path = 'C:\\Users\\matsh\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data'

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

def open_browser_with_new_profile(number):
    global browsers
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={chrome_profile_path}')
    options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory={prefix_for_profiles}asdadagafsdfwer{number}')
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    
    web = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    web.get(URL)


threads = [

]

for number in range(ALL_PROFILES):
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=open_browser_with_new_profile, args=(number, )))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Errors:

```
user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I came to the conclusion that if you create a new User Data folder for each web browser, everything works correctly. However, this does not suit me. Is there a solution to not creating a new User Data?

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument(r"--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir")
options.add_argument(r"enable-profile-shortcut-manager")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

try:
    options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\matsh\\Desktop\\BrowsersOpenner\\User Data1")
    options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory=Matthew")
    web1 = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('chromedriver.exe'), options=options)

    web1.get(URL)
except:
    pass

try:
    options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\matsh\\Desktop\\BrowsersOpenner\\User Data2")
    options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory=Faker")
    web2 = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('chromedriver.exe'), options=options)

    web2.get(URL)
except:
    pass

try:
    options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\matsh\\Desktop\\BrowsersOpenner\\User Data3")
    options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory=Someone")
    web3 = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('chromedriver.exe'), options=options)

    web3.get(URL)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: This seems like an edit to the question, rather than an answer.

Comment: @Derek T. Jones, it looks like a stuffing post, not a reply to a topic. And my "no answer" is editing based on my tests.